# yam.platform and yam.connect.loginButton callback is not called in IE 11

Tags: javascript, sdk, yammer

Trying to log into Yammer in IE 11, by using yam.login and yam.connect.loginButton
something like this:

```
yam.platform.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
            setCookie("yammer_access_token", response.access_token.token);
            callback();
        } else {
            $('#yamButton').on('click', function () {
                yam.login(function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    if (response.authResponse) {
                        setCookie("yammer_access_token", response.access_token.token);
                        callback()
                    }
                });
            });   
        }
    });
```

The Yammer login dialog window is opened when #yamButton is clicked, and I can login to yammer. The popup dialog will then redirect to yammer oauth to authenticate and it will prompt an alert that the window will be closed. But after it is closed, the callback function for yam.login does not fire...

I have added all the Yammer URLs and the host URL of my app into the trusted sites in IE.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I'm facing exactly the same problem